# Entity Framework Code First Read Only Key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

In EF 4.1 RC1, I have a simple entity like say `Category`, with a property ID int. Can I make that a read only property and still have it work?

If not, how do you protect the PK/FK?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to define your ID property like this:

```
public int ID { get; internal set; }
```

... then define your DbContext class in the same assembly as the "Category" class. It'll have write access to the property, but classes outside of the assembly won't.

If you need to define your DbContext in a separate assembly, you can use the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute to let that assembly see the internals of your "Category" class.